# Magento won't ADD ITEMS to my cart with some customers. Works on my PC though

Tags: magento

I have a Magento shopping cart installed at:

http://www.freeminds-store.com/

The only problem I have is that (although it doesn't happen on my 
computer), many customers complain that when they hit the "Add to 
Cart" button it either doesn't add anything to the cart, either on 
the big listing or individual product page. IE browsers, especially 
64-bit, seem to be the worst, but it happens on others. 
Then sometimes the last of the checkout process fails and won't go 
anywhere. I just need someone to check the code and fix the button 
problem. We are a non-profit struggling so please not too much  $$$

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `"Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT"` to YES in your admin backend (system config > web > session validation). I had the same problem and it fixed it.